# .gitignore didn't ignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have my CakePHP project which has different config content than config on server.

I used this command to create .gitignore file:
`cd /var/www/html/tmc && touch .gitignore`

Then I wrote this into the file:

```
/app/tmp/*
/app/Config/core.php
/app/Config/database.php
/vendors/*
```

However when I push, these files are changed again.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm, is your path to /app and /vendors `/var/www/html/tmc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your files are already being tracked by Git, in which case Git will disregard your `.gitignore` rules and commit the files anyway.  If you want to make Git forget about the files you will have to `git rm` them from the repository:

```
git rm --cached app/Config/core.php
git rm --cached app/Config/database.php
```

and so on for all the files you want to ignore.

After running these commands your working tree should have changes corresponding to the removes you have done.  After you commit and push, the files will no longer be tracked.

Comment: Should I run these commands on my local repository or on server or on both?

Comment: Run the commands locally.  Git commands are generally run locally, though they (frequently) will talk to the remote repo.

Comment: Btw, remove first forward-slash from paths. Btw how do I check all --cached data?

Comment: It appears that changes are still uploaded anyway. Can anybody recommend me some guide/reference for this case?

Comment: Did you `git rm` followed by a commit and push?  After this, the files should no longer be a part of the repo, unless you added them again by mistake.

Comment: What does `git status` show you?  Is `app/Config/core.php` listed as being an untracked file?

Answer (score 0):

execute from root directory even if not ignore by .gitignore file
step 1
 git update-index --assume-unchanged filename

step 2 go to
 exclude file which is inside .git/info and copy past the filename
 inside exclude file

e.g. to exclude rootfile/abc.txt file
git update-index --assume-unchanged rootfile/abc.txt and in exclude file which is inside .git/info file   rootfile/abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37677391/19620781

The response here was phenomenal, but just to simplify...

Make sure you're running inside the root folder of your entire project. For example...

[image]

Once that is done, run the following command.

```
git rm --cached (insert file or directory you want to ignore here)
```

If you get this error

```
fatal: not removing (insert file or directory you want to ignore here) recursively without -r
```

Run this:

```
git rm -r -f --cached (insert file or directory you want to ignore here)
```